# Hide element and its contents behind a transparent element

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I was looking for a way to hide a panel behind another one, partially transparent, with CSS animations without success until I realized I could shrink it progressively by applying a **transition** to its `height`:

```js
$( '#box' ).on( 'click', function() {
 $( this ).addClass( 'closing' );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5%;
}

#panel, #box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}

#panel {
  height: 200px;
}

#box {
  height: 50px;
}

  #box.closing {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 3s ease;
  }

.box {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 35%, rgba(65, 85, 100, 0.2) 40%, rgba(65, 85, 100, 0.2) 42%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 50%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 55%, rgba(70, 85, 100, 0.2) 60%, rgba(70, 85, 100, 0.2) 75%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 90%);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(2, 3, 4, 0.6);
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.35vw 1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            box-shadow: 0 0.35vw 1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.box:before, .box:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:before {
    background-image: radial-gradient(200% 200% at bottom right, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0) 50%, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0.6) 75%);
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw;
    left: 0;
}

.box:after {
    background-image: radial-gradient(200% 200% at bottom left, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0) 50%, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0.6) 75%);
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5vw;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel" class="box">
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
<div id="box" class="box">
  Click me
</div>
```

However, as you can see in this demo, the contents of the panel remains visible while and after hiding it.

I expanded the transition to:

```
#box.closing {
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: height 3s ease, visibility 3s ease;
}
```

And, although now the contents hide as well, it is still happening after the `height` animation.

How could I animate them both without JS — I used it here just to have a way to trigger the animation — so as soon as the `height` starts reducing and "pass-through" its contained elements, they also start disappearing, like if the panel swallows the contents and then vanishes.

**Updated**

This are the results after using @hungerstar solution so far:

```js
$( '#box' ).on( 'click', function() {
 $( this ).addClass( 'closing' );
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5%;
}

#panel, #box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}

#panel {
  height: 200px;
}

#box {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
}

#box.closing {
    z-index: -1;
    top: -52px; /* 50px height + 1px top border + 1px bottom border */
    transition: top 3s ease;
}

.box {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 35%, rgba(65, 85, 100, 0.2) 40%, rgba(65, 85, 100, 0.2) 42%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 50%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 55%, rgba(70, 85, 100, 0.2) 60%, rgba(70, 85, 100, 0.2) 75%, rgba(25, 40, 55, 0.2) 90%);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(2, 3, 4, 0.6);
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.35vw 1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            box-shadow: 0 0.35vw 1vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.box:before, .box:after {
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:before {
    background-image: radial-gradient(200% 200% at bottom right, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0) 50%, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0.6) 75%);
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5vw;
    left: 0;
}

.box:after {
    background-image: radial-gradient(200% 200% at bottom left, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0) 50%, rgba(185, 190, 195, 0.6) 75%);
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5vw;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel" class="box">
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
<div id="box" class="box">
  Click me
</div>
```

Comment: What about `#box.closing { overflow: hidden; }`?

Comment: Hmmm... I tried with the editor in here, first without the `visibility`, and it indeed solves the issue but a thin blue border remains, like if the box isn't fully hidden. Then I re-added the `visibility` and the blue box vanishes completely but with a noticeable "blinking" because the second animation is still happening after the first one. How could I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

OP requested that borders be animated out of view.

I might change up the approach to your animation and animate the bottom box up and behind the first.

```js
var $box = $( '#box' );

$box.on( 'click', function () {
  $box.addClass( 'closing' );
} );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5%;
}

#panel,
#box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}

#panel {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

#box {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
}

#box.closing {
  z-index: -1;
  top: -52px; /* 50px height + 1px top border + 1px bottom border */
  transition: top 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
<div id="box">
  Click me
</div>

<p>
  I'm here so you can see what happens to content after the animation.
</p>
```

#### Original Answer

Use `overflow: hidden;`.

```js
var $box = $( '#box' );

$box.on( 'click', function () {
  $box.addClass( 'closing' );
} );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 5%;
}

#panel,
#box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}

#panel {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

#box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

#box.closing {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="panel">
  Lorem ipsum dolor...
</div>
<div id="box">
  Click me
</div>
```

Comment: I was commenting while you prepared the answer. What about the thin blue "border" left visible?

Comment: I don't see any blue but I do see that the border is left after the height is zero. Updated answer using a different method of animating the box out of view.

Comment: Although I mentioned the element would hide behind a (partially) transparent element, I failed to show this transparency in the pseudo-code. When applying the technique to the real layout, it works perfectly, but the element remains visible behind the panel because of the said transparency. I'll update the original code so you can see what I'm talking about. However, by rearranging some classes I was able to make the original solution using `overflow` to work, even though the final code didn't end lexically organized as I originally intended. In any event, thank you for the help.

Comment: Try `background` instead of `background-image` and then add `background-color: #fff;`.